# How to wake from sleep programmatically if lid closed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to wake system from sleep programmatically, is there any way to do this?

I have read following link:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2004/qa1340.html

this only talk about getting notification , but not sure is there any way to wake system from sleep?

I appreciate some thread to the information...

***Update:***

As per the suggestion I tried with IOPMSchedulePowerEvent

Code I have used:

```
NSCalendarDate  *timeIntervalSinceNow = [NSCalendarDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:40];
IOReturn result = IOPMSchedulePowerEvent ((CFDateRef)timeIntervalSinceNow, NULL, CFSTR(kIOPMAutoWake));
```

Result:

It fails in MacBook if lid closed

Am I doing some thing wrong or Any solution?

Comment: See also https://github.com/iccir/Fermata but like others it just "prevents" sleep when in clamshell, dunno if there's anyway to "wake up" a sleeping mac...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can schedule wake up events with IOPMSchedulePowerEvent through the power manager.  You may be able to schedule an immediate wake up.  [pmset](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) is a command line wrapper for the power manager.  You can also prevent sleep with IOCancelPowerChange in certain cases.

You may be able to prevent sleep or wake up by generating a mouse or key event.  One way to generate events is with CGPostKeyboardEvent.

Edit:

Normal sleep is different from clamshell closed sleep.  To affect the latter you must write a kernel extension like [Insomnia](http://binaervarianz.de/projekte/programmieren/meltmac/).

Comment: How could you wake up by generating an event?  If the computer's asleep, your code isn't running.

Comment: thanks,let me give a try. you mean this will work even for lid close based sleep right?

Comment: I tried with IOPMSchedulePowerEvent to wakeup from sleep , it fails in MacBook if lid closed.

Comment: You did not mention the lid being closed in your question.  You will have to write a kernel extension to prevent sleep when the lid is closed.  [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo) does this.  Once you have written such a kernel extension, you will have a better idea about waking from sleep when the clamshell is down, but I suspect you will just have to prevent sleep.

Comment: Actually, InsomniaX is a wrapper for the [Insomnia](http://binaervarianz.de/projekte/programmieren/meltmac/) kernel extension which has source available.