# The type or namespace name 'ManagementEventWatcher' not found

Tags: c#, managementeventwatcher

Why do I get *The type or namespace name 'ManagementEventWatcher' not found* in the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

class Program {
    public ManagementEventWatcher mgmtWtch;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mgmtWtch = new System.Management
                     .ManagementEventWatcher("Select * From Win32_ProcessStartTrace");
        mgmtWtch.EventArrived += new    
            System.Management.EventArrivedEventHandler(mgmtWtch_EventArrived);
        mgmtWtch.Start();
    }
}
```

I think my dll doesn't have this method, but how to check?

Comment: Please rephrase the question. Explain what exactly it is you're struggling with.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ManagementEventWatcher' not found

Comment: Are you missing the assembly reference?. See the step by step way of [How to add the system.management.dll reference into a project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22223788/3240038).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you added the reference as well as the using? eg

```
using System.Management;
```

is not enough.. you need to add the reference to System.Management too.

Comment: Ok, have you got an example ?
I'm just start to learn c#

I FOUND \o/
Thanks BugFinder

Answer (score 0):

Your Main method is static, but your mgmWtch variable is not. Declare it as as static.

Comment: True, but problems are always her :/

Comment: What version of visual studio / .net are you on?

Comment: BugFinder found a "bug"... I just forgot to add reference in the project.
But thanks you for your help