# Is the ManagementEventWatcher class no longer available in the System.Management namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm getting the following error message:

> The type or namespace name 'ManagementEventWatcher' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have included `System.Management` in my project references, yet the type cannot be found.

I have run Visual Studio as administrator and still get the same result. Has `ManagementEventWatcher` gone away?

Comment: You probably have the wrong CLR (.NET Framework Version) selected in the project.  If your DLL is building for CLR 2 it can't reference a CLR 4 assembly and therefore the type cannot be found.

Answer (score 10):

You are probably missing the assembly reference to `System.Management.dll`. The using statement just brings names into scope, to save you typing the prefix: it doesn't actually add a DLL reference into the project.

If you have added the reference and didn't include `using System.Management` in your class then you gets this error message. Also if you just include `using System.Management` in your class and didn't include it's reference into your project, you will get a similar error message. You have to add the reference of `System.Management.dll` to your project just like I have shown below.

---

Go to the Solution Explorer, and expand your project, right click on the References folder/option and select Add References from the context menu. Now select the .Net tab and select the `System.Management` from the list and click OK.

In case if you have VS2010, VS2012, VS2013...
Add the reference by right click on the References folder/option and select Add References from the context menu. Now select the Assemblies and then Framework tab and select the `System.Management` from the list and click OK.

[image]

Comment: That is the assembly. From question: "I have included System.Management in my project references"

Comment: The error that author put in the question is **The type or namespace name 'ManagementEventWatcher' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)** And I provided its solution and it will remove this error

Comment: Why down vote @PatrickHofman ? I provide the valid solution. The author asking about the error it facing and I explained it why it facing. If you have a better answer, then provide it here...

Comment: Who said I was voting you down?

Comment: @Mark: can you please clarify this? Did you add the reference to your project as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you've selected the correct CLR version for the DLL that you are adding.  I looked in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1 folder and the System.Management.dll found in that folder still had the class.  I added a reference and a using statement and I was able to construct it.