# Can I wake a Mac from sleep programmatically?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wake from sleep programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315685/how-to-wake-from-sleep-programmatically)

I'm trying to see if OS X supports a feature to wake a Mac from sleep at a predetermined time?

PS. I'm obviously asking for an API from a developer's perspective.

Comment: There are apps such as Aurora that do exactly that, so the answer is yes. Not sure where it is in the API though.

Comment: So what happens if I've got a MacBook and your program wakes it up with the lid closed?

Comment: I can say from a Window perspective. The notebook wakes up and waits for 2 minutes for a user's input and if there's none, or if a resident program does not extend it, the OS goes back to sleep. I was wondering if OS X has a similar feature?

Comment: Yes, you can add power assertions too.  See the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac///#/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPMLib_header_reference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @NicholasRiley: Very nice, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

See this question: [How to wake from sleep programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315685/how-to-wake-from-sleep-programmatically)

Also see OS X's "Wake On Demand" feature. It works with the Bonjour Sleep Proxy on your Airport or Time Capsule: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774