# App Sandbox Temporary Exception Entitlement to Schedule Power Event

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, appstore-sandbox

I am working on a sandboxed app. I am looking to schedule power events (via `IOPMSchedulePowerEvent`) that allows the app to put the Mac to sleep and wake it up at prescribed times, while retaining the app sandbox.

Currently, the only way I can make the IOPMSchedulePowerEvent work is by running the app as "root" and de-enabling the sandbox. This is achieved by following the steps in one of my previous posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234870/authenticate-macos-app-to-wake-mac-from-sleep?noredirect=1#comment75479670_44234870)

Is there a temporary exception entitlement that would allow me to schedule these power events while retaining the app sandbox and not forcing the app to run as root? The closest I have come to finding a solution so far is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html). I'll admit, I'm fairly inexperienced in working with the temporary exception entitlements, so any insight provided would be most helpful!

is starting off with the `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.iokit-user-client-class` entitlement the proper place to start? How would I go about actually using the entitlement once it's included in the entitlements file?

**Edit** I think I've found a workaround that works well enough. I went away from the scheduling power events/entitlements route entirely, and I am instead preventing idle sleep using `kIOPMAssertionTypeNoIdleSleep`, while still allowing the display to sleep. This re-do of logic is simpler and accomplishes by in large the same goal I was previously trying to achieve. The Stack Overflow post that shows the related documentation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596319/how-to-programmatically-prevent-a-mac-from-going-to-sleep).

Here's a copy of the code, plus a little extra I included to remove some warnings/deprecations:

```
#import <IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h>

// kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep prevents display sleep,
// kIOPMAssertionTypeNoIdleSleep prevents idle sleep

// reasonForActivity is a descriptive string used by the system whenever it needs 
// to tell the user why the system is not sleeping. For example, 
// "Mail Compacting Mailboxes" would be a useful string.

// NOTE: IOPMAssertionCreateWithName limits the string to 128 characters. 
//    Do what we need to with the string types

NSString *reasonForActivity = @"Put Display to Sleep, Keep Machine Awake";

CFStringRef cfStringReasonForActivity = (__bridge CFStringRef)reasonForActivity;

IOPMAssertionID assertionID;

//    create assertion to prevent system from IDLE sleeping

IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoIdleSleep,
                                               kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, cfStringReasonForActivity, &assertionID);
if (success == kIOReturnSuccess)
{
//  Add the work you need to do without 
//  the system sleeping here.

success = IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID);
//  The system will be able to sleep again. 
}
```

Comment: The usual solution for keeping the main app sandboxed while running code with system privileges would be a combination of SMJobBless and an XPC service.